# Difficult style for the map

Tags: geoserver, mapserver, style, mapnik, cartocss

There is a task before me of generating images as shown below. The main problem is the signs which must be placed outside the polygon (if they do not fit in it), and the lines should connect the sign with the point on the polygon.

Are there any solutions exist in free map renders?

Map example:

[image]

Comment: From your mockup it looks as if most labels could fit within your polygons. Overusing leader lines is a poor cartographic design decision.

Answer (score 4):

MapServer does support label LEADER since 6.2.

http://mapserver.org/mapfile/leader.html

Example:

[image: Label leader example from RFC]